# /boot/map~ OK to delete when /boot/map does not exist?

Tags: boot, backup, delete

I know that files that end with a tilde(~) are OK to delete because they are backups. However, I found `/boot/map~`, when `/boot/map` does not exist. Can I delete this? It is 117761 bytes (118 kilobytes), so it is big (text wise).

Comment: Can you post the results of this command (edited into your question): `ls -l /boot`? Nice to have a good look before recommending this file be `mv-ed` to `map~_bak` at least :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly an unneeded file as the naming convention for the map files in `/boot` is as follows:

```
andrew@athens:~$ ls /boot | grep -E *map*
System.map-4.4.0-15-generic
System.map-4.4.0-22-generic
```

Test this on your own system, this is on Xenial Xerus 16.04. The file can be safely left in place but if you are at all worried simply back the file up for a few days:

```
sudo mv /boot/map~ /boot/map~_bak
```

and delete after a period of safe running. This is a very conservative approach...